# Why we have to put same finger three times for attendance register?

Tags: interaction-design, gestures

Can anybody tell me why I have to put same finger for three times. If I get it mistake at first, it finally show message "Not Matched". One time should be enough!

Why do i have to wait so long to know my input are wrong.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPLRNnRPdEM

[image]

Comment: If you compare this with's apple's finger print scanner, you only have to hold it once. It seems like a terrible user experience

Comment: On the UI, it looks like they're cropping off a good portion of your finger. If the UI is reflecting the actual image they're getting, the camera/sensor might be too close to the glass to get an adult's entire fingerprint reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can relate this question with the asking password and confirm password [which is ineffective.](http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-the-confirm-password-field-must-die/)

In your case, the device can actually take the details of fingerprint at **one shot**. but it wants you to remember how you push your finger. Pushing 3 times can help to remember your finger position.

But i personally believe this is bad example of user experience. User don't that kind of memorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referrring to the actual experience in the video, the first three presentations of each finger appear to be registering the print, using three reads appears to be the device registering repeated matches to ensure references are apparant across each read.

Once the prints are registered the user presents their index finge twice with failed readings, then wipes the screen and the subsequent presentation works on both fingers first time. The issue appears to be with the physical glass not any UI issues.